# Drawing a photo from the camera on a canvas?

Tags: flutter

I want to take a photo with the image_picker library that stores the file on the phone sd card.

I want to then load this image so that i can draw it with a CustomPaint widget by drawing the image on the canvas.

I have tried to load the image with both FileImage and Image.file
but this doesn't work because the 'Image' in the CustomPaint extends NativeFieldWrapperClass2 and isn't an Image widget

Is there anyone who knows how to load a photo and draw it on a canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `ui` package version of `Image` (as distinct from the widget called `Image`)

Import the `ui` package, and create a method to return the `ui.Image`:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

  Future<ui.Image> load(String filename) async {
    var file = File(filename);
    var bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
    var codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(bytes);
    var fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return fi.image;
  }
```

Use `ui.Image` to draw. You may need a transform to shrink it.